# Circom compiler removes crucial constraint after simplication

Tags: circom, circomlib

While testing Num2Bits template with n=8 from circomlib I faced this:

R1CS without simplification:

```
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[0] ] * [ main.out[0] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[1] ] * [ main.out[1] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[2] ] * [ main.out[2] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[3] ] * [ main.out[3] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[4] ] * [ main.out[4] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[5] ] * [ main.out[5] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[6] ] * [ main.out[6] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[7] ] * [ main.out[7] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [  ] * [  ] - [ 21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495616main.out[0] +21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495615main.out[1] +21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495613main.out[2] +21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495609main.out[3] +21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495601main.out[4] +21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495585main.out[5] +218
```

R1CS with full simplification activated:

```
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[0] ] * [ main.out[0] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[1] ] * [ main.out[1] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[2] ] * [ main.out[2] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[3] ] * [ main.out[3] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[4] ] * [ main.out[4] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[5] ] * [ main.out[5] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[6] ] * [ main.out[6] ] - [  ] = 0
[INFO]  snarkJS: [ 218882428718392752222464057452572750885483644004160343436982041865758084956161 +main.out[7] ] * [ main.out[7] ] - [  ] = 0
```

Why it removes the last constraint? It looks like the very important constraint that must be included to the R1CS since it checks the sum of bits and the original input. Or I miss something?

Comment: This does not answer your question but as a side note: I am on version 2.1.5 and noticed this exact issue a few days ago without simplification. However, when trying to see whether a particular production codebase had this issue, I noticed circom did indeed constrain their output. I don't know why it simplifies as such but I would expect it is likely fine when used within larger circuit that makes use of the output.

Answer (score 0):

The simplification is happening because the addition constraint is getting removed, which is because when you compile with circom, --O2 is the default. Add --O1 or --O0 at the end of your circom command to avoid addition constraint deletion.